# Replace OpenGL glUniform functions with templated alternatives

Tags: c++, templates, opengl

I am following an OpenGL tutorial, and at the point where I am right now, it teaches you to write a Shader class. However, there is something about it that I don't like, namely the functions that allow you to set uniform values. The tutorial gives the following:

```
void Shader::setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
{         
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value); 
}
void Shader::setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
{ 
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value); 
}
void Shader::setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
{ 
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value); 
}
```

When I saw this, my first tought was: "This has to be done better, I think templates might be able to help me". So I started working on that, up to the point where I have the following Shader class:

```
class Shader
{
public:
    Shader();
    Shader(std::string const& vertex_path, std::string const& fragment_path);

    //Activates the shader
    void use();

    using size_type = unsigned int;

    //Uniform utility functions
    template<typename T>
    void setUniform(std::string const& name, T const& v0) const
    {
        using RemovedRefCV = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        if constexpr (Traits::IsValidType<RemovedRefCV> >())
        {
            auto location = glGetUniformLocation(name);

            if constexpr(std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, int>)
            {
                glUniform1i(location, v0);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, unsigned int>)
            {
                glUniform1ui(location, v0);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, float>)
            {
                glUniform1f(location, v0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(false, "Shader::set<std::string const& name, T v0>: Type T must be int, unsigned int or float");
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void setUniform(std::string const& name, T const& v0, T const& v1) const
    {
        using RemovedRefCV = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        if constexpr (Traits::IsValidType<RemovedRefCV> > ())
        {
            auto location = glGetUniformLocation(name);

            if constexpr(std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, int>)
            {
                glUniform2i(location, v0, v1);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, unsigned int>)
            {
                glUniform2ui(location, v0, v1);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, float>)
            {
                glUniform2f(location, v0, v1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(false, "Shader::set<std::string const& name, T v0, T v1>: Type T must be int, unsigned int or float");
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void setUniform(std::string const& name, T const& v0, T const& v1, T const& v2) const
    {
        using RemovedRefCV = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        if constexpr (Traits::IsValidType<RemovedRefCV> > ())
        {
            auto location = glGetUniformLocation(name);

            if constexpr(std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, int>)
            {
                glUniform3i(location, v0, v1, v2);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, unsigned int>)
            {
                glUniform3ui(location, v0, v1, v2);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, float>)
            {
                glUniform3f(location, v0, v1, v2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(false, "Shader::set<std::string const& name, T v0, T v1, T v2>: Type T must be int, unsigned int or float");
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void setUniform(std::string const& name, T const& v0, T const& v1, T const& v2, T const& v3) const
    {
        using RemovedRefCV = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        if constexpr (Traits::IsValidType<RemovedRefCV> > ())
        {
            auto location = glGetUniformLocation(name);

            if constexpr(std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, int>)
            {
                glUniform4i(location, v0, v1, v2, v3);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, unsigned int>)
            {
                glUniform4ui(location, v0, v1, v2, v3);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RemovedRefCV, float>)
            {
                glUniform4f(location, v0, v1, v2, v3);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(false, "Shader::set<std::string const& name, T v0, T v1, T v2, T v3>: Type T must be int, unsigned int or float");
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void setUniform(std::string const& name, size_type count, const T* v) const
    {

    }

private:
    GLuint ID;
    bool loaded;

    class Traits
    {
    private:
        template<typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
        struct IsValidTypeHelper : std::false_type
        {

        };

        template<typename T>
        struct IsValidTypeHelper<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(T), float> ||
            std::is_same_v<decltype(T), int> ||
            std::is_same_v<decltype(T), unsigned int>
        >
        >
            : std::true_type {};

        template<typename T>
        struct IsValidTypeT : IsValidTypeHelper<T>::type {};

    public:
        template<typename T> using IsValidType = typename IsValidTypeT<T>::type;
    };
};
```

As you can see, I have already created an overload for vectors, but I am not sure how to implement it, as I want to try to replace as many `glUniform***()` calls with my Shader::setUniform() function as possible. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386687/using-templates-to-manage-gluniform-functions) question, but it didn't fully adress what I am looking for.

Comment: I see two problems with your approach. First, you are reimplementing function overloading with these templates and cascaded `if constexpr`s. Simple overloading with a single greedy template to catch implicit conversions will get you the same result. Second, you make the type of uniform implicitly deduced from the type of the thing you pass in, which might trigger obscure bugs when you try to address an uniform with the wrong type, while using an explicit function name catches the mismatch.

Comment: There are about 12-14 functions to implement for this and I would advise doing them individually rather than with clever template functions.  The various overloads are pretty trivial to implement and they make your code much clearer, at least that`s what I discovered when I did my impl (like you I thought a template solution would be good but eventually gave it  up for clarity).

Comment: That's a good idea. Also, do you have any suggestions on how to do the same for matrices, without having to specify the size of the matrix? Or is this not possible?

Comment: @MivVG I only have individual overloads for 3x3 and 4x4 float matrices as those are the only ones I use.  Again, the impl is trivial and you can make individual function overloads for your mat3 and mat4 types (which call glProgramUniformMatrix3fv and glProgramUniformMatrix4fv respectively).

Comment: Okay, thanks alot for helping me!